# Creating comboboxes in MS Access forms for a Postgresql backend database

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

I have a Postgresql database which records road incidents. The database have a main table to record road accident details. The database also have a few reference tables. For example, there is a "incident_type" table where I add or update incident/acciednt types. The main "incident" table have a "incident_type" column which gets the values from the "incident_type" table. The relationships are correctly setup using primary key and foreign key relationship. HeidiSQL recognizes this and shows the values from the reference table (incident type) while edititng the referenced table (incident). See the screenshots where HeidiSQL shows a combo box with the options from the incident type table, and store the incident type id for the selected option. This is all good and sound.

[HeidiSQL shows the options from another table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ens.png)

[HeidiSQL stores the primary key of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhJ8G.png)

Now, I am trying to use MS Access as a front end for the database. However, the Access Forms do not recognize the relatinships and use text boxes where it should have a combo box.

I have added the relationship in the Access Relationships window and then tried to add Combo Boxes manually in the forms but it is not showing the columns I need. My incident_type table have an id columd, and an incident_type column. It also has two columns to track the record creation and update time. When I use a combo box wizard in Access, it shows the id column and the two datetime columns but not the incident_type column. See the screenshots below -

[incident type table description with columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVaUJ.png)

[The combo box wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iWCH.png)

Comment: A combo box has its own record source. Normally Access should show all fields. Yo can try to create a simple query in your incident_type table to see if Access then can access all fields. If yes, you can use this query (or the SQL string) as data source for your combo box. If you can also not find the field in the query, you have to check your main source, if Access in general have access to all fields in the incident_type table.

Comment: set the combobox rowsource to the incident_type table (combo box properties under data tab).  Then assuming incident_type has two columns that are in order  ID and Type.  move to the format tab and set Column Count to 2 and set Column Widths to 0,1.  however many columns your rowsource has  set the columns you don't want to see to 0 width.  If you change the order in the rowsource change the order in Column Widths

Comment: @Zen: This is a good idea. I will try this out.

Comment: @HansUp: The main backend database is Postgres and I can't change the table names from Access. I can try changing it in Postgres but not reluctant to do so as it have some data. What i can do is make a backup of the original database and apply your suggestions.

Comment: @Zen: I created a simple query on the incident_type Table with all the columns (including the PK/id and the type column). However, when I try to create a combo box based on this query, the query wizard only shows the pjk/id column, not the column witht he type name. Not sure if this is a bug or we are missing something.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I am trying to use MS Access as a front end for the database. However, the Access Forms do not recognize the relationships and use text boxes where it should have a combo box.

Huh? The wizard that creates the form for you will often make such bad decisions. On the other hand, the wizards that create a form for you are just that - some "helper" or so called "training wheels" to get you up and running.

As a "developer"?

Well, then just delete the text box, and in design mode drop in a combo box, and you can even let the wizard connect up and build that combo box for you. Hardly a need to cry and call mommy here, right?

So, in design mode, just delete the text box, and drop in a combo box. The combo box will have the pick list "SQL data source", and upon selection of a combo choice, then you have the data bound column, (the column in the current form) that the ID or value of the combo box selection is to be saved into.

So, the column used to save into the current ONE record for the current form is thus this setting:

[image]

So, the form in question should ONLY be based on the linked table to the data base server. I suppose you can use a query, but in near all cases, EACH form is to be based on ONE table, and not some SQL that attempts to join multiple tables into that form.

So, it takes what, about 10 seconds of your time to delete the text box, and then drop in a combo box, and setup the data source that drives the choice(s) for that combo box, and then you also need to set what data column on the current form that the results of that choice should be saved into.

The fact that access by default might choose to place a text box on the form for you? Sure, but if you going to put on a developer’s hat, then you as the developer of this application can simply add/drop in a combo box as needed into any form you wish.

As noted, those forms using linked tables to that database server will in near all cases ONLY have one table involved in that form's data source. The combo box(s) you drop into that form can have any other data source, but we still at the end of the day working with, and saving ONE record that we are editing into the database.

If you need that form to deal with relational data editing of additional records that belong to the given form? Then you use a sub form for that purpose.

So, in those cases in which you want to present a list of choices to the user? Then YOU the developer can simply drop in a combo box to present that list of choices. You fast realize after oh say a few hours, that you the developer has to control this choice, and you fast drop the use of the wizards etc. that creates forms for you.

And as a last FYI?

You don't EVER want your users to open table(s) in question for direct editing. Provide a good UI for your users, and that may well include a continues form with a combo box, or even creating a datasheet, and flipping into design view, you can once again drop in a combo box, and using the wizards only takes a few extra seconds of your time.

So, at the end of the day?
ODBC linked tables does not provide to MS-access information about relationships you setup on the database server. There are boatloads of database server systems, and the ODBC specification does not send or tell access about relationships on that database server from a vendor that has little to do with Microsoft or MS-Access.

However, as noted, the fact that ODBC does not send to the client the enforced relationships you have on some database vendors product "X", "Y" or "Z"?

As noted, you can build the UI you wish, and easily introduce combo boxes into your UI. As such, introduction of a simple combo box is something you the developer have to take control of when using external ODBC linked tables.

So, do remember, that often a combo box will have 2 columns. Typical first column is the PK id of the database, and then the 2nd column is the display column.

So,  you might want to select a part number, and thus you have these columns:

ID: The database primary key value (PK)
PartDescription: The description of the part

Now, in our form that we drop the combo box into?

That bound column is likely to be named Part_ID.

So, the combo box will return the part table PK id, but the column that PK value is to be saved into is on the current form/record, and that column name you set in the combo box will be say part_id.

So, this in effect gets you a relational join to the parts table into the current record.  As noted, no such relationships have to be defined in the database for this to work. And in fact, be this c++, .net code, or even a web based system? You find that all such tools leave this choice up to the developer to "hook up" such values. The developer tools in most cases don't care. The only issue is when your code or "UI" attempts to save some values that are not valid, or say might break or violate the relationships you enforced. While the client side tools often don't care, an error message by the database system will trigger and occur. So, the UI development tools tend to NOT know about relationships, nor enforce them. However, it stands to reason that a valid list of choices in a combo box will of course pass the relational rules you setup in the database.

However, often a look of these so called "helper" tables, or so called lookup tables are not always part of a enforced relationship in the database system (they perhaps should be). So, I seen a lot of systems where a good many simple combo boxes for choosing simple values are not part of enforced relationships.

Last but not least?
If you just looking to display the data, and the user does not require a combo box choice? Then build a query as a left join to the table used during data entry (along with the combo box). Thus, for display of such information, you of course will use a SQL join to display such values when the goal is for display, and not editing.

## Edit: Above narrative does not help nor answer the question.

First up, as noted, my apoloiges here. The above narrative is based on me assuming the quesiton of "why" one has to use the combo box wizard. Turns out the question was WHY does the combo box wizard NOT work!
That is vast differnet question, and thus my above narrative does not answer, nor help the poster here.

It would be trival to adopt and use the combo box wizard here, but hte question is not about having to use the combo box wizard (my incorrect assumptiong here), but the question is why does the combo box wizard not work!!!

I suggest you flip the linked table into design mode.
(ignore the message about read only - answer "yes" anyway)

Note the data types here:

[image]

So, everything the poster wants to do is correct. However, linked tables using so called "memo" or very long text columns? The combo box wizard DOES NOT pick up nor allow choosing of such columns. You probably can edit the SQL manually for the combo box, but at the end of the day, the table design on the server should be changed, and then the table(s) in Access client will require a table re-linking for the changes to be seen correctly.

Use of such long text columns also not all that great for the database engine, since in most cases, such columns can't be indexed.

So, the reason why the column does not appear in the wizard is due to the column type chosen on the server.

Once again, my public apologies to the poster here, as I read the question of why one has to go though all the trouble to use the combo box wizard, which of course is rather easy to do and is "minor".

The issue is in this question and case, the combo box wizard DOES NOT WORK! and that is a vast different, and rather legitimate question by the poster.

So, the poster's question stands, the poster's question was a good question, and my long narrative is incorrect and does NOT help the poster here. However, this follow up edit should allow the poster to correct this issue and problem. So the solution here is to change the server side column type to a column of standard lenght (one <= 255 characters). However, often such a change is not allowed on such databases. Thus, then the 2nd suggestion would be to create a view with that column "casted" to a standard text type of column.

Comment: Actually, my public apologies here. I read your question as to why you HAVE to use the wizard to create the combo box (a minor effort on your part). However, reading your question again? The question is WHY the combo box wizard does not work!!! - a Mount Everest of a different question!!! So, my answer and narrative DOES NOT help nor address your problem.  The correct answer is that column type is most likely seen as a "memo" text column, and combo boxes don't work with those. (column width has to be less then 255 characters. Flip the linked table into design mode, and note the column types.

Comment: See my edit and follow up. Your issue was NEVER that you had to use a combo box wizard, but that it FLAT OUT was not working!!! -- see my edit for solutions.

Comment: Thanks. Changing the datatype from TEXT to VARCHAR in the Postgresql backend does the trick. Now Access see them.

Comment: Thanks for your response and suggestion. I have good experience with Postgres but have very little knowledge of how Access works. 

Your suggestion works but I will probably create the form using a better tool. I thought Access will be the easier route but it is not.

Comment: That is great. As noted, my apologies as I thought the issue was you having to use the combo box wizard which is easy. Reading close, you WHERE using the wizard and it was not working! So, issue was the column type.  Access combo boxes don't like the "larger" unlimited type of text columns (they can contain a huge amounts text and thus are not appropriate for combo box). Changing the column to a "smaller/shorter" type of column works.  In fact, a lot of systems will "not" like those super large column types for a combo box selection, so these types of issues are not limited to Access